# Do we really need "release-upgrade"?

Tags: discussion, tags

https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/release-upgrade

This tag makes no sense to me, it looks like it's just a subset of what should just be in "upgrade" anyway, should we just merge/symlink it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with your opinion that we don't need the [release-upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/release-upgrade) tag. I suggest we replace this tag with [release-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/release-management) or [upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/upgrade) where appropriate.

Comment: release-upgrade should be a synonym of 'upgrade'

Comment: Do we need [tag:release-management]?